# In Vi-editor How do I find and change date format of a specific date?

Tags: regex, date, vim, find, vi

My Data looks like this (2 record(s) from the file which is open in vi-editor) -

```
445544|2016-02-09|026|111|W108576|1|2015-02-13|2017-02-17|WHI|2016-02-10|SC|RN

114433|2016-02-07|046|366|WR71X253|4|2016-02-09|2017-02-17|GE|2016-02-08|SC|RN
```

I want to change the date format of the last date value from YYYY-mm-dd to mm-dd-YYYY i.e.

```
'2016-02-10' to '02-10-2016' & 
'2016-02-08' to '02-08-2016'
```

Following is what I have tried

```
^.*\(\<[0-9]{4}\>\)-\(\<[0-9]{2}\>\)-\(\<[0-9\]{2}\>\)|\w\+|\w\+\n$
```

It says - E486: Pattern not found:

I know that once I will have the find pattern I can do -

```
:STARTLINE,ENDLINEs/<PATTERN to find>/<PATTERN to replace>/g
```

Please help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change a single line by pressing this in normal mode:

```
$2T-Xdbf|i-<c-r>"<esc>
```

If you want to know what is happened, just press those keys, and see what is changed in your buffer.

To apply it to all lines:

### Marco

btw, in vimgolf, macro will usually beat `:cmd` :-)

```
qq$2T-Xdbf|i-<c-r>"<esc>+@qq
```

then press `@q`

**Note**, since I used nested macro, pls do a `qqq` before recording macro, so that the old stuff in `q` is cleared.

### Normal command

You can wrap those normal command into `:norm` too:

```
:%norm! $2T-Xdbf|i-^R"^[
```

**Note**,

- above `^R` you press `ctrl-v ctrl-r`
- the `^[` you press `ctrl-v ESC`

Comment: I love this solution, however since we are Vim Golf'ing, is there any advantage of `^R"` over `p`? I feel like it would still work and save a keystroke.

Comment: * A perfect solution Kent. Can you please briefly reply with what these shortcuts do and

* Is there a common abstract term for this cryptic language ? 

* Also suggesting an improvement -> (c-r) and (esc) could be easily confused with (right) 'Ctrl' and 'Escape' keys. You should thank god, he made me read till the EOF ;)

Comment: @nitinr708 you can open vim with the example text, press the keys in my answer, to see what it happens, I won't explain what all those keys do, you can find out by yourself, e.g `:h X`, `:h f` etc. Regarding the `<c-r>` if you had used vim for some time, you won't get confused.

Answer (score 2):

```
s/\v^([^|]+\|){9}\zs(\d{4})-(\d{2}-\d{2})/\3-\2/
```

- `\v` very magic, avoids too many `\`s
- `^([^|]+\|){9}\zs` from start of line, 9 columns delimited by `|`. By using `\zs`, regex following it will be start of match for replacement
- `(\d{4})-(\d{2}-\d{2})` capture YYYY and MM-DD as two groups
- `\3-\2` re-arrange as needed

Without `\zs`

```
s/\v^(([^|]+\|){9})(\d{4})-(\d{2}-\d{2})/\1\4-\3/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
%s/\(.*\|\)\(\d\{4\}\)-\(\d\{2\}\)-\(\d\{2\}\)/\1\3-\4-\2/g
```

- `\(.*\|\)` **greedily** match everything up to the last `|` that also satisifies
- `\(\d\{4\}\)-\(\d\{2\}\)-\(\d\{2\}\)` match YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 1):

The shortest regex solution is to use `\zs`, `\v` or very magic if you
have it  enabled by default, and  to take advantage of  greediness. If
you match  a `.*`, everything  is matched.  The engine then  goes back
step by step trying  to match what's left to match.  This way the date
will be the last date present in the line, aways.

```
s/\v.*\zs(\d{4})-(\d\d-\d\d)/\2-\1
```